# Using xPath to grab the value of an attribute

Tags: xpath, automation

From a much larger XML document I am able to reference the exact line I am targeting, but unsure how to grab the value of a specific attribute.

The xPath that gets me there is:

```
(//DPM)[2]//*[name()='cip4:RunList]
```

The value that I need is the last number of this attribute:

> cip4:SourceTrimBox="36.000000 36.000000 648.000000 **688.500000**"

I don't care if I have to deal with the whole string. I can parse it out.
Here's the entire line:

```
<cip4:RunList cip4:SourceMediaBox="0.000000 0.000000 684.000000 760.500000" cip4:SourceTrimBox="36.000000 36.000000 648.000000 688.500000"/>
```

I've been using Visual Studio Code, along with an XPath Tester extension, but not getting the results I need. I have a thread going on another forum for Esko Automation Engine regarding this problem, but I'm not getting the response I need. The people replying want me to change a legacy workflow, and that could have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit quirky, but I guess that you are restricted to XPath-1.0 expressions.
So try

```
substring-after(substring-after(substring-after((//DPM)[2]//*[name()='cip4:RunList']/@cip4:SourceTrimBox,' '), ' '),' ')
```

The result should be `688.500000`.
If you only need the value of the attribute, it's much simpler:

```
(//DPM)[2]//*[name()='cip4:RunList']/@cip4:SourceTrimBox
```